# Documenting reference class method arguments

Tags: r

I know that reference class methods are documented inline using a docstring as the first line of a method body. Is there an official way of documenting the method arguments like you would with an S4 method? Roxygen does not seem to pick up @param tags.

EDIT 1:

```
test <- setRefClass("test")
test$methods(method1 = function(x) {
"
@param x this is the x param
\\describe{
  \\item{\\code{x}}{some description}
}
"
})
test$help(method1)
```

Here is a trivial example. The latex is processed but the roxygen tag is not. I am not saying there is a bug in roxygen because that seems to conform to R standards so my guess is that no one actually bothers documenting the arguments of RC methods. What I really want to know is if there is an "official" or "best" way to do this as I am just starting to play with reference classes.

Comment: Can you add an example of your non-working code?

Comment: I supplied an example like you asked.